# Increase accuracy of GRU, keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to predict the next note of a piano using the previously played notes. The input and target data(values from classical piano .mid files) is formatted as

```
x_train=[ [[1,2,3,4,5],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]], [[1,2,3,4,5],[4,5,6,7,8],[0,0,0,0,0]] ]
#notes not played yet are [0,0,0,0,0]
#y_train is the next note played
y_train= [ [[4,5,6,7,8]], [[10,11,12,13,14]] ]
```

**Problem:** My accuracy is low(~45%) and the next note predicted is always the same ( or eventually becomes same)

Training-

```
(x_train,y_train)=create_data()

x_train=np.array(x_train)
y_train=np.array(y_train)

x_train=x_train.astype("int")
y_train=y_train.astype("int")

x_train=x_train[:500]
y_train=y_train[:500]

model=keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.Input(shape=(500,5)))
model.add(keras.layers.GRU(5,activation='linear'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1*5))

model.compile(
        loss=keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError(),
        optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001),
        metrics=["accuracy"]
    )

model.fit(x_train,y_train)
```

Creating a song with the first note taken from x_train:

```
currentNote=x_train[0].tolist()

i=0
while i<499:
    feed=[currentNote]
    feed=np.array(feed)
    output=model.predict(feed)
    output=np.absolute(output)
    output=output[0].astype("int").tolist()
    print(output)                       # printing next note predicted
    currentNote[i+1]=output
    i+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, you are using the wrong loss. You should be using `categorical_crossentropy` or `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` because this is a classification problem. Also, your final activation function (which you didn't specify) should be `'softmax'`.

Also, you should *sample* from the output probabilities rather than taking the highest probability. There is a Tensorflow [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/text_generation) which covers that.

> Note: It is important to sample from this distribution as taking the argmax of the distribution can easily get the model stuck in a loop.

This is *roughly* how you can do it:

```
example_batch_predictions = model(X_test)

sampled_indices = tf.random.categorical(example_batch_predictions[0], 
                                        num_samples=1)
sampled_indices = tf.squeeze(sampled_indices,axis=-1).numpy()
```

```
array([41, 60,  3, 31, 47, 21, 61,  6, 56, 42, 39, 40, 52, 60, 37, 37, 27,
       11,  6, 56, 64, 62, 43, 42,  6, 34,  1, 30, 16, 45, 46, 11, 17,  8,
       26,  8,  1, 46, 37, 21, 37, 53, 34, 49,  5, 58, 11,  9, 42, 62, 14,
       56, 56, 30, 31, 32, 63, 53, 10, 23, 35,  5, 19, 19, 46,  3, 23, 63,
       61, 11, 57,  0, 35, 48, 32,  4, 37,  7, 48, 23, 39, 30, 20, 26,  1,
       52, 57, 23, 46, 56, 11, 22,  7, 47, 16, 27, 38, 51, 55, 28])
```